# jasperserver - SOAP PHP Example

Tags: php, soap, jasperserver

When I run the soap example, I have following error/warning:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /var/www/vtigercrm540/Jasper/client.php on line 300
```

I can Login but every time I login(also with wrong credentials) , I go the `listReports.php` page and I see :

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1 in /var/www/vtigercrm540/Jasper/client.php on line 300
```

List reports:

```
Current Directory: /

[..]


Exit
```